# Gfile error Tensorflow in ROS

Tags: python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.

I am trying to create a node for image classification using ROS and Tensorflow.

If I run this script with python, everything works perfectly with some differents networks:

```
import pyrealsense2 as rs
import numpy as np
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf

# Configure depth and color streams
pipeline = rs.pipeline()
config = rs.config()
config.enable_stream(rs.stream.color, 640, 480, rs.format.bgr8, 30)

print("[INFO] Starting streaming...")
pipeline.start(config)
print("[INFO] Camera ready.")

# download model from: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API#run-network-in-opencv
print("[INFO] Loading model...")
PATH_TO_CKPT = "frozen_inference_graph.pb"

# Load the Tensorflow model into memory.
detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
    od_graph_def = tf.compat.v1.GraphDef()
    with tf.compat.v1.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
        serialized_graph = fid.read()
        od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
        tf.compat.v1.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')
    sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=detection_graph)

# Input tensor is the image
image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
# Output tensors are the detection boxes, scores, and classes
# Each box represents a part of the image where a particular object was detected
detection_boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
# Each score represents level of confidence for each of the objects.
# The score is shown on the result image, together with the class label.
detection_scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
detection_classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
# Number of objects detected
num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')
# code source of tensorflow model loading: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ml-training-image-classifier-using-tensorflow-object-detection-api/
print("[INFO] Model loaded.")
colors_hash = {}
while True:
    frames = pipeline.wait_for_frames()
    color_frame = frames.get_color_frame()

    # Convert images to numpy arrays
    color_image = np.asanyarray(color_frame.get_data())
    scaled_size = (color_frame.width, color_frame.height)
    # expand image dimensions to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
    # i.e. a single-column array, where each item in the column has the pixel RGB value
    image_expanded = np.expand_dims(color_image, axis=0)
    # Perform the actual detection by running the model with the image as input
    (boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run([detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
                                                feed_dict={image_tensor: image_expanded})

    boxes = np.squeeze(boxes)
    classes = np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32)
    scores = np.squeeze(scores)

    for idx in range(int(num)):
        class_ = classes[idx]
        score = scores[idx]
        box = boxes[idx]

        if class_ not in colors_hash:
            colors_hash[class_] = tuple(np.random.choice(range(256), size=3))

        if score > 0.6:
            left = int(box[1] * color_frame.width)
            top = int(box[0] * color_frame.height)
            right = int(box[3] * color_frame.width)
            bottom = int(box[2] * color_frame.height)

            p1 = (left, top)
            p2 = (right, bottom)
            # draw box
            r, g, b = colors_hash[class_]

            cv2.rectangle(color_image, p1, p2, (int(r), int(g), int(b)), 2, 1)
            cv2.putText(color_image, str(class_)+" "+str(score), p1, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, (int(r), int(g), int(b)))

    cv2.namedWindow('RealSense', cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
    cv2.imshow('RealSense', color_image)
    cv2.waitKey(1)

print("[INFO] stop streaming ...")
pipeline.stop()
```

In the other hand, I have created a ROS package where I launch the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

#Creador: AMC 2021
#Funcion: Nodo de clasificacion de imagen con TensorFlow
#Recibe: RealSense [Image(/camera/color/image_raw)]
#Envia: Realsense [Image(/image_classified)]
import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
from std_msgs.msg import String
import pyrealsense2 as rs
import numpy as np
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf
import struct

class TENSORFLOW_ROS_CLASS:

# Function: __init__
#
# Comments
# ----------
# Define neural network
#
# Parameters
# ----------
#
# Returns
# -------
    def __init__(self):

        # download model from: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API#run-network-in-opencv
        print("[INFO] Loading model...")
        PATH_TO_CKPT ="frozen_inference_graph.pb"

        # Load the Tensorflow model into memory.
        detection_graph = tf.Graph()
        with detection_graph.as_default():
            od_graph_def = tf.compat.v1.GraphDef()
            with tf.compat.v1.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
                serialized_graph = fid.read()
                od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
                tf.compat.v1.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')
            sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=detection_graph)

        # Input tensor is the image
        image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
        # Output tensors are the detection boxes, scores, and classes
        # Each box represents a part of the image where a particular object was detected
        detection_boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
        # Each score represents level of confidence for each of the objects.
        # The score is shown on the result image, together with the class label.
        detection_scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
        detection_classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
        # Number of objects detected
        num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')
        # code source of tensorflow model loading: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ml-training-image-classifier-using-tensorflow-object-detection-api/
        print("[INFO] Model loaded.")
        colors_hash = {}

# Function: main
#
# Comments
# ----------
# Set up the node, the publications and subsciptions.
#
# Parameters
# ----------
#
# Returns
# -------

    def main(self):

        rospy.init_node('tensorflow_ros')
        rospy.loginfo("Iniciado nodo tensorflow_ros")

        #Publications
        self.classification_pub = rospy.Publisher("image_classified", Image, queue_size=100)

        #Subscriber
        rospy.Subscriber("/camera/color/image_raw", Image, self.callback_image)

        rospy.spin()

# Function: callback_image
#
# Comments
# ----------
#
# Parameters
# ----------
# msg: Data of the topic
#
# Returns
# -------

    def callback_image(self,msg):
        color_image=Image()
        color_image=msg

        #Publish topic
        self.classification_pub.publish(color_image)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    detector=TENSORFLOW_ROS_CLASS()
    detector.main()
```

And the error is this one:

```
[INFO] Loading model...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sara/catkin_ws/src/tensorflow_ros/script/tensorflow_ros.py", line 106, in <module>
    detector=TENSORFLOW_ROS_CLASS()
  File "/home/sara/catkin_ws/src/tensorflow_ros/script/tensorflow_ros.py", line 40, in __init__
    serialized_graph = fid.read()
  File "/home/sara/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 117, in read
    self._preread_check()
  File "/home/sara/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 79, in _preread_check
    self._read_buf = _pywrap_file_io.BufferedInputStream(
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: frozen_inference_graph.pb; No such file or directory
```

Actually the frozen_inference_graph.pb file is in the same directory of the script, so I don't know what is different respect the python execution.

Any ideas or other example to run a DNN in ROS using tensorflow?

Best regards.
Alessandro

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/374452/gfile-error-tensorflow-in-ros/) by [Alessandro Melino](https://answers.ros.org/users/52370/alessandro-melino/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2021-03-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Actually the frozen_inference_graph.pb file is in the same directory of the script, so I don't know what is different respect the python execution.

I believe this is similar/a duplicate of #q235337.

Summarising: the `CWD` (*current working directory*) when running a node with `rosrun` or `roslaunch` is not the same as when you start a script yourself.

The `CWD` for all nodes is `$HOME/.ros`. So unless there is a file called `frozen_inference_graph.pb` in `$HOME/.ros`, the error you mention is expected.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alessandro Melino](https://answers.ros.org/users/52370/alessandro-melino/) on 2021-03-23**:
Yes, that was the problem, I must use the whole path of the file to reference it. Thank you.